# cakephp2x Model, View,Controller Naming Conventions

Tags: cakephp-2.0

i am new in the cakephp2x and i dont know how to named the controller and view and model files in the cakephp 2x.

for the simple Event module i have

```
contoller : EventsController.php  
model : Event.php
vide : Events  ( folder Name )
```

now this look like http://example.com/events

Now my i want the link look like this http://example.com/itemsbidders
for the above url i have named the file as below

```
controller : ItemsBiddersController.php
model : ItemBidder.php
view : ItemsBidders
```

but i am getting 404 page not found Error in this page.

so can you tell me my mistake. advice me for this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HABTM link tables you order model names alphabetically and first model kept plural:

```
Controller : BiddersItemsController.php
Model : BiddersItem.php
View : BiddersItems
```

And URL now looks like this: http://example.com/bidders_items (with underscore to separate models).

Remember, first letter capitalised and singular for folders: Controller / Model / View

Now to get URL you want above, you will need to create a router declaration in your Config/routes.php file like:

```
Router::connect('/itemsbidders',
    array('controller' => 'bidders_items', 'action' => 'index'));
```